# NSURLConnection or NSurl?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurl

what is the difference between `NSURLConnection` and `NSURL`?

i mean if i am downloading a file, does it make and difference which one i use?

Rgds

for:

```
     NSString *myUrl = @"http://www.test.com/"; 
     NSString *returnData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: myUrl]];
```

or

```
     NSString *myUrl = @"http://www.test.com/"; 
     NSURLRequest *myRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:myUrl] ]; 
     NSString *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:myRequest returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
```

whats the difference?

thks

Answer (score 1):

- The Connection

  > An `NSURLConnection` object provides support to **perform the loading** of a **URL request**.
- The Request

  > `NSURLRequest` objects represent a URL load request in a manner independent of protocol and URL scheme.

  E.g. `requestWithURL`:

  > Creates and returns a URL request for a specified URL with default cache policy and timeout value.

  ```
  + (id)requestWithURL:(NSURL *)theURL
  ```
- The URL

  > The `NSURL` class provides a way to manipulate URLs and the resources they reference. `NSURL` objects understand URLs as specified in RFCs 1808, 1738, and 2732. ...
  >
  > To get the contents of a URL, `NSString` provides `stringWithContentsOfURL:` and `NSData` provides `dataWithContentsOfURL:`.

References:

- [NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURL)

Comment: it means nsurlconnection is just to load a webpage, whole webpage will be display,  nsurl is for getting data within the webpage?

Comment: No, read the links provided by The MYYN. NSURL is a model class that represents a URL. NSURLConnection is a class than ables you to download data from a URL. In order to use an NSURLConnection, you need to create a URL request using NSURLRequest, which uses NSURL to represent it's URL. Read the Cocoa documentation entitled Cocoa URL Loading System.

Comment: for:

NSString *myUrl = @"http://www.google.com";
NSString *returnData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: myUrl]];

or

NSString *myUrl = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [ [NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:myUrl] ];
NSString *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:myRequest returningResponse: nil error: nil ];

whats the difference?

Comment: I would be clearer if you editted your above comment with the code into the question, as it's almost unreadable in a comment. The answer however is that there is very little difference; the second method gives you more scope to handle errors. Both methods are syncronous; you should use asyncronous networking instead so your application does not lock up whilst fetching from the network.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing about NSURLConnection is its asynchronous behaviour so that you dont have to wait until the url is loaded.